# Minimalistic python webframework

Tags: python, web-frameworks

I used to create web applications with Django framework, but now I have to create only simply web GUI for python application. I would be very glad if someone will recommend to me any small python web framework.

Comment: [What's a good lightweight Python MVC framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986/whats-a-good-lightweight-python-mvc-framework)

Comment: There are far too many duplicates...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good lightweight Python MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986/whats-a-good-lightweight-python-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[web.py](http://webpy.org/) is a popular choice for this sort of thing.

*"web.py is a web framework for Python that is as simple as it is powerful."*

Answer (score 2):

And of course let's not forgot [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)!

Comment: A single file is about as minimal as you can get.

Comment: To put a whole framework into a single file is not the best way to structure code.